# AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'Adam' , I am getting this error

Tags: keras, adam

I am getting this error
AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'Adam' for the below.

```
classifier.compile(optimizer= keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Try tf.keras.optimizers.Adam

Answer (score 0):

The Keras has been moved to Tensorflow package since Tensorflow 2.x; so you should use `tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam`.

The details usage can be found at [Adam Optimizer](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/adam/)